# Docker Rootless "Permission denied" on mounted dir

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions

I've created a Docker Rootless container where I mounted a directory from my host to the container. However, I'm unable to change the permissions of my directory or modify existing files within it.

[Permission Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY5Ew.png)

In the above image, the file test.txt was created from the directory on the host machine that is mounted to this container.

[nobody, nogroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYNmG.png)

In this image, we can see that the directory "/log" belongs to "nobody".

The issue seems to be related to Docker Rootless because I didn't have this problem when using Docker without the rootless mode.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I tried to change the user, but unfortunately, my attempts were unsuccessful. As a beginner in Docker, I'm not sure what steps to take next, and I haven't been able to find any suitable resources on Google.

[chown & chmod not permitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceR8K.png)

Regards,

Comment: For the chown and chmod on the host you need `sudo`.  Docker rootless should have even less permisisons on the host, so you're not going to have luck there.  For the rest, I wish I knew.